# VBA excel Duplicate Removal not working

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have a function to a button which get activated once i click it , it shows the data rows ( with specific conditions so it doesn't give all the rows back)from two identical sheets in a new sheet called (Issue_SumofShares) .The issue is when cross-checking ,so many data rows are repeated due to to comparing all the rows from the first sheet (NBG_RegionaData) with the first row from the second sheet (NBG_ComparisonRegionData) then go to the second row of the second sheet and that goes on . I know that i can remove the duplicates (remove rows with the same values in the first and second column ) manually or by the "Remove Duplicates" button , but i want to remove duplicates automatically when i press the button , before showing the results , so i added the DeleteRows sub , and tried calling it , but it is not working , so can somebody tell me where i am going wrong or tell me how i can make the duplicate removal automatic that it happens automatically before opening the sheet (Issue_SumofShares) after pressing its button .
Here is my code :

```
' A function which shows all the same projects with sum of shares <> 1

Function VerifySumofShares() As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

'Get the number of rows in NBG_Data_Comparison_Region
MAX_Row = Sheets(NBG_ComparisonRegionDataWorksheetName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Get the number of rows in NBG_Data_Region
MAX_Row1 = Sheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).UsedRange.Rows.Count

' having names for each comparing part to make the if statment easier
Dim NBGMonth As String
Dim NBGYear As String
Dim NBGCarmaker As String
Dim NBGProject As String
Dim NBGFamily As String
Dim NBGStatus As String
Dim NBGShare As Integer
Dim NBGCst As String
Dim CompMonth As String
Dim CompYear As String
Dim CompCarmaker As String
Dim CompProject As String
Dim CompFamily As String
Dim CompStatus As String
Dim CompShare As Integer
Dim CompCst As String
Dim RNumber As Integer



'Count the Sum of shares for same projects which <> 1

Issue_SumofSharesCnt = 0
Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName = "Issue_SumofShares"
' Clear Issue Som of Shares Data Sheet

Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells.Clear

' Customize Issue_SumofShares sheet

Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(1, 1) = "Report of projects with multiple customers and Sum of Shares that does not equal 100%"

With Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(1, 1).Font
    .Bold = True
    .Size = 14
    .color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With

SOP = "C"
Status = "AD"
Customer = "A"
Product = "B"
Responsible = "AT"
Family = "AA"
Project = "AB"
carmaker = "AJ"
Share = "BQ"
GeoRegion = "BF"

With Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName)
    .Range("A2") = "Data Row"
    .Range("F2") = "Project"
    .Range("C2") = "SOP (dd-Month-yy QQ)"
    .Range("D2") = "Product"
    .Range("I2") = "Responsible"
    .Range("E2") = "Family"
    .Range("G2") = "Carmaker"
    .Range("H2") = "Share"
    .Range("B2") = "Customer"
    .Range("J2") = "Region"
    .Range("K2") = "Status"
    .Range("A2:Z2").Font.Bold = True
End With

' Take the data of the NBG_Data_Comparison_Region
For Row = 2 To MAX_Row


     'CompMonth = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, SOP).Value
     'CompMonth = DatePart("m", CompMonth)

     CompYear = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, SOP).Value
     CompYear = DatePart("yyyy", CompYear)

     CompCarmaker = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, carmaker).Value
     CompProject = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Project).Value
     CompFamily = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Family).Value
     CompStatus = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Status).Value
     CompShare = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Share).Value
     CompCst = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, "A").Value

     ' Take the data from NBG_Data_Region sheet to be compared with each row of the NBG_Data_Comparison_Region sheet

    For Row1 = 2 To MAX_Row1


    If Row1 >= MAX_Row1 Then
      Exit For
    End If


    'NBGMonth = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, SOP).Value
    'NBGMonth = DatePart("m", NBGMonth)

    NBGYear = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, SOP).Value
    NBGYear = DatePart("yyyy", NBGYear)

    NBGCarmaker = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, carmaker).Value
    NBGProject = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, Project).Value
    NBGFamily = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, Family).Value
    NBGStatus = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, Status).Value
    NBGShare = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, Share).Value
    NBGCst = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, "A").Value









  ' StatusBar Show

   Application.StatusBar = "VerifySumofShares. Progress: " & Row & " of " & MAX_Row

       'Check if any row with a SOP date in the previous or current years and if it is a D-IN or OPP is found and add it to the IssueSOP_Date sheet

       ' NAF 20161208
       'Test with comparison of YEAR and MONTH
       ' If (NBGMonth = CompMonth And NBGYear = CompYear And CompCarmaker = NBGCarmaker And CompProject = NBGProject And CompFamily = NBGFamily And CompShare + NBGShare <> 1 And NBGCst <> CompCst) Then
       ' With Year only
        If (NBGYear = CompYear And CompCarmaker = NBGCarmaker And CompProject = NBGProject And CompFamily = NBGFamily And CompShare + NBGShare <> 1 And NBGCst <> CompCst) Then

            'Customization of the Issue_SumofShares sheet to show the NBG Data Row , Cst, SOP , Product, Responsible,Family , Carmaker , Share , Status and the GeoRegion of the data which the condition applies to
            'NBGStatus <> "LOST" And CompStatus <> "LOST" And
            'And CompCarmaker = NBGCarmaker And CompProject = NBGProject And CompFamily = NBGFamily And CompShare + NBGShare <= 0.99 And CompShare + NBGShare > 1

            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "A").Value = Row1
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "B").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, Customer).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "C").Value = GetMonthAndQuarter(Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, SOP).Value)
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "D").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, Product).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "E").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, Family).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "F").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, Project).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "G").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, carmaker).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "H").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, Share).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "I").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, Responsible).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "K").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, Status).Value
            ' Region As String
            Region = ""

            'Add any other GeoRegion which is also responsible in the recorded data


            If Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, "BC") Then
            Region = Region + "@EMEA"
            End If

            If Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, "BD") Then
            Region = Region + "@AMERICAS"
            End If

            If Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, "BE") Then
            Region = Region + "@GCSA"
            End If

            If Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, "BF") Then
            Region = Region + "@JAPAN&KOREA"
            End If
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "J").Value = Region





            'Count the number of the cases recorded

            Issue_SumofSharesCnt = Issue_SumofSharesCnt + 1

            'If there is no items , the Message to show

        ElseIf (Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, SOP).Value = "There are no items to show in this view.") Then

     End If

         Call DeleteRows

     Next Row1

     Next Row



' Send the Counter to show on the Menu sheet on the button involved

VerifySumofShares = Issue_SumofSharesCnt



    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic


  End Function




 Sub DeleteRows()
  Dim Rng As Range


With Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName
    Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
    Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to mod it for your sheetname.  I tested it and it works great.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Dim Rng As Range, LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("B" & LastRow))
Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

If your are looking to delete duplicares and the entire row try the code below.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicatesCells_EntireRow()

Dim rng As Range, LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("A1", Range("B" & LastRow))
rng.EntireRow.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

I hope that helps bud!

```
Function VerifySumofShares() 'As Integer

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.Calculation = xlManual

' having names for each comparing part to make the if statment easier

Dim NBG_ComparisonRegion As Excel.Worksheet
Dim NBG_Region As Excel.Worksheet
Dim Issue_SumofShares As Excel.Worksheet
Dim NBG_DataWorksheetName As Excel.Worksheet
Dim NBGMonth As String, NBGYear As String
Dim NBGCarmaker As String, NBGProject As String
Dim NBGFamily As String, NBGStatus As String
Dim NBGShare As Integer, NBGCst As String
Dim SOP As String, Status As String
Dim Customer As String, Product As String
Dim Responsible As String, Family As String
Dim Project As String, carmaker As String
Dim Share As String, GeoRegion As String
Dim CompMonth As String, CompYear As String
Dim CompCarmaker As String, CompProject As String
Dim CompFamily As String, CompStatus As String
Dim CompShare As Integer, CompCst As String
Dim RNumber As Integer, MAX_Row As Long
Dim MAX_Row1 As Long, Row As Integer
Dim Row1 As Integer, Issue_SumofSharesCnt As Integer
Dim Region As String

Set NBG_ComparisonRegion = Sheets("NBG_ComparisonRegionData")
Set NBG_Region = Sheets("NBG_RegionaData")
Set Issue_SumofShares = Sheets("Issue_SumofShares")
Set NBG_DataWorksheetName = Sheets("NBG_DataSheetName")

'Get the number of rows in NBG_Data_Comparison_Region
MAX_Row = NBG_ComparisonRegion.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Get the number of rows in NBG_Data_Region
MAX_Row1 = NBG_Region.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'Count the Sum of shares for same projects which <> 1
Issue_SumofSharesCnt = 0

Issue_SumofShares.Cells.Clear

' Customize Issue_SumofShares sheet

Issue_SumofShares.Cells(1, 1) = "Report of projects with multiple customers" & _
                            "and Sum of Shares that does not equal 100%"

With Issue_SumofShares.Cells(1, 1)
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = 14
    .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With

SOP = "C"
Status = "AD"
Customer = "A"
Product = "B"
Responsible = "AT"
Family = "AA"
Project = "AB"
carmaker = "AJ"
Share = "BQ"
GeoRegion = "BF"

With Issue_SumofShares
    .Range("A2") = "Data Row"
    .Range("F2") = "Project"
    .Range("C2") = "SOP (dd-Month-yy QQ)"
    .Range("D2") = "Product"
    .Range("I2") = "Responsible"
    .Range("E2") = "Family"
    .Range("G2") = "Carmaker"
    .Range("H2") = "Share"
    .Range("B2") = "Customer"
    .Range("J2") = "Region"
    .Range("K2") = "Status"
    .Range("A2:Z2").Font.Bold = True
  End With

 ' Take the data of the NBG_Data_Comparison_Region
 For Row = 2 To MAX_Row

 'CompMonth = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, SOP).Value
 'CompMonth = DatePart("m", CompMonth)

 CompYear = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, SOP).Value
 CompYear = DatePart("yyyy", CompYear)
 CompCarmaker = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, carmaker).Value
 CompProject = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, Project).Value
 CompFamily = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, Family).Value
 CompStatus = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, Status).Value
 CompShare = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, Share).Value
 CompCst = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, "A").Value

 ' Take the data from NBG_Data_Region sheet to be compared with each row of the NBG_Data_Comparison_Region sheet

For Row1 = 2 To MAX_Row1

If Row1 >= MAX_Row1 Then
  Exit For
End If


'NBGMonth = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, SOP).Value
'NBGMonth = DatePart("m", NBGMonth)

 NBGYear = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, SOP).Value
 NBGYear = DatePart("yyyy", NBGYear)
 NBGCarmaker = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, carmaker).Value
 NBGProject = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Project).Value
 NBGFamily = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Family).Value
 NBGStatus = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Status).Value
 NBGShare = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Share).Value
 NBGCst = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, "A").Value ' error = 1


Application.StatusBar = "VerifySumofShares. Progress: " & Row & " of " &    MAX_Row

   'Check if any row with a SOP date in the previous or current years and if it is a D-IN or OPP is found and add it to the IssueSOP_Date sheet

   ' NAF 20161208
   'Test with comparison of YEAR and MONTH
   ' If (NBGMonth = CompMonth And NBGYear = CompYear And CompCarmaker = NBGCarmaker And CompProject = NBGProject And CompFamily = NBGFamily And CompShare + NBGShare <> 1 And NBGCst <> CompCst) Then
   ' With Year only
If (NBGYear = CompYear And CompCarmaker = NBGCarmaker And CompProject = NBGProject And CompFamily = NBGFamily And CompShare + NBGShare <> 1 And NBGCst <> CompCst) Then

        'Customization of the Issue_SumofShares sheet to show the NBG Data Row , Cst, SOP , Product, Responsible,Family , Carmaker , Share , Status and the GeoRegion of the data which the condition applies to
        'NBGStatus <> "LOST" And CompStatus <> "LOST" And
        'And CompCarmaker = NBGCarmaker And CompProject = NBGProject And CompFamily = NBGFamily And CompShare + NBGShare <= 0.99 And CompShare + NBGShare > 1

     Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "A").Value = Row1
     Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "B").Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Customer).Value
     'Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "C").Value = GetMonthAndQuarter(NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, SOP).Value)
     Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "D").Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Product).Value
     Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "E").Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Family).Value
     Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "F").Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Project).Value
     Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "G").Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, carmaker).Value
     Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "H").Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Share).Value
     Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "I").Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Responsible).Value
    ' Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "K").Value = WNBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Status).Value

      Region = ""


    If NBG_DataWorksheetName.Cells(Row1, "BC") Then ' error  "BC" = 55
        Region = Region + "@EMEA"
    End If

    If NBG_DataWorksheetName.Cells(Row1, "BD") Then ' error  "BD" = 56
        Region = Region + "@AMERICAS"
    End If

    If NBG_DataWorksheetName.Cells(Row1, "BE") Then ' error  "BC" = 57
        Region = Region + "@GCSA"
    End If

    If NBG_DataWorksheetName.Cells(Row1, "BF") Then ' error  "BC" = 58
        Region = Region + "@JAPAN&KOREA"
    End If

    Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "J").Value = Region '< Going to have issues "J" Is not a number - should be 10

    Issue_SumofSharesCnt = Issue_SumofSharesCnt + 1



    ElseIf (NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, SOP).Value = "There are no items to show in this view.") Then

 End If

    ' Call DeleteRows

 Next Row1

 Next Row


VerifySumofShares = Issue_SumofSharesCnt


CleanUp:

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

   Set NBG_ComparisonRegion = Nothing
   Set NBG_Region = Nothing
   Set Issue_SumofShares = Nothing
   Set NBG_DataWorksheetName = Nothing

 End Function
```

There are so many issues i tried to fix a bunch of them with notes. Please let me know if you have issues fixing the rest.

```
    Sub VerifySumofShares()

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Application.Calculation = xlManual

    ' having names for each comparing part to make the if statment easier

    Dim NBG_ComparisonRegion As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim NBG_Region As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Issue_SumofShares As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim NBG_DataWorksheetName As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim NBGMonth As String, NBGYear As String
    Dim NBGCarmaker As String, NBGProject As String
    Dim NBGFamily As String, NBGStatus As String
    Dim NBGShare As Integer, NBGCst As String
    Dim SOP As String, Status As String
    Dim Customer As String, Product As String
    Dim Responsible As String, Family As String
    Dim Project As String, carmaker As String
    Dim Share As String, GeoRegion As String
    Dim CompMonth As String, CompYear As String
    Dim CompCarmaker As String, CompProject As String
    Dim CompFamily As String, CompStatus As String
    Dim CompShare As Integer, CompCst As String
    Dim RNumber As Integer, MAX_Row As Long
    Dim MAX_Row1 As Long, Row As Integer
    Dim Row1 As Integer, Issue_SumofSharesCnt As Integer
    Dim Region As String

    Set NBG_ComparisonRegion = Sheets("NBG_ComparisonRegionData")
    Set NBG_Region = Sheets("NBG_RegionaData")
    Set Issue_SumofShares = Sheets("Issue_SumofShares")
    Set NBG_DataWorksheetName = Sheets("NBG_DataSheetName")

    'Get the number of rows in NBG_Data_Comparison_Region
    MAX_Row = NBG_ComparisonRegion.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'Get the number of rows in NBG_Data_Region
    MAX_Row1 = NBG_Region.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Count the Sum of shares for same projects which <> 1
    Issue_SumofSharesCnt = 0

    Issue_SumofShares.Cells.Clear

    ' Customize Issue_SumofShares sheet

    Issue_SumofShares.Cells(1, 1) = "Report of projects with multiple customers" & _
                                "and Sum of Shares that does not equal 100%"

    With Issue_SumofShares.Cells(1, 1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 14
        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With

    SOP = 3
    Status = 30
    Customer = 1
    Product = 2
    Responsible = 46
    Family = 27
    Project = 28
    carmaker = 36
    Share = 69
    GeoRegion = 58

    With Issue_SumofShares
        .Range("A2") = "Data Row"
        .Range("F2") = "Project"
        .Range("C2") = "SOP (dd-Month-yy QQ)"
        .Range("D2") = "Product"
        .Range("I2") = "Responsible"
        .Range("E2") = "Family"
        .Range("G2") = "Carmaker"
        .Range("H2") = "Share"
        .Range("B2") = "Customer"
        .Range("J2") = "Region"
        .Range("K2") = "Status"
        .Range("A2:Z2").Font.Bold = True
      End With

     ' Take the data of the NBG_Data_Comparison_Region
     For Row = 2 To MAX_Row

     'CompMonth = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, SOP).Value
     'CompMonth = DatePart("m", CompMonth)

     CompYear = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, SOP).Value
     CompYear = DatePart("yyyy", CompYear)
     CompCarmaker = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, carmaker).Value
     CompProject = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, Project).Value
     CompFamily = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, Family).Value
     CompStatus = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, Status).Value
     CompShare = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, Share).Value
     CompCst = NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, 1).Value

     ' Take the data from NBG_Data_Region sheet to be compared with each row of the NBG_Data_Comparison_Region sheet

    For Row1 = 2 To MAX_Row1

    If Row1 >= MAX_Row1 Then
      Exit For
    End If


    'NBGMonth = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row1, SOP).Value
    'NBGMonth = DatePart("m", NBGMonth)

     NBGYear = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, SOP).Value
     NBGYear = DatePart("yyyy", NBGYear)
     NBGCarmaker = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, carmaker).Value
     NBGProject = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Project).Value
     NBGFamily = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Family).Value
     NBGStatus = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Status).Value
     NBGShare = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Share).Value
     NBGCst = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, 1).Value


    Application.StatusBar = "VerifySumofShares. Progress: " & Row & " of " & MAX_Row

       'Check if any row with a SOP date in the previous or current years and if it is a D-IN or OPP is found and add it to the IssueSOP_Date sheet

       ' NAF 20161208
       'Test with comparison of YEAR and MONTH
       ' If (NBGMonth = CompMonth And NBGYear = CompYear And CompCarmaker = NBGCarmaker And CompProject = NBGProject And CompFamily = NBGFamily And CompShare + NBGShare <> 1 And NBGCst <> CompCst) Then
       ' With Year only
    If (NBGYear = CompYear And CompCarmaker = NBGCarmaker And CompProject = NBGProject And CompFamily = NBGFamily And CompShare + NBGShare <> 1 And NBGCst <> CompCst) Then

            'Customization of the Issue_SumofShares sheet to show the NBG Data Row , Cst, SOP , Product, Responsible,Family , Carmaker , Share , Status and the GeoRegion of the data which the condition applies to
            'NBGStatus <> "LOST" And CompStatus <> "LOST" And
            'And CompCarmaker = NBGCarmaker And CompProject = NBGProject And CompFamily = NBGFamily And CompShare + NBGShare <= 0.99 And CompShare + NBGShare > 1

         Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, 1).Value = Row1
         Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, 2).Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Customer).Value
         Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, 3).Value = GetMonthAndQuarter(NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, SOP).Value)
         Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, 4).Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Product).Value
         Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, 5).Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Family).Value
         Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, 6).Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Project).Value
         Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, 7).Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, carmaker).Value
         Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, 8).Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Share).Value
         Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, 9).Value = NBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Responsible).Value
         Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, 11).Value = WNBG_Region.Cells(Row1, Status).Value

          Region = ""


        If NBG_DataWorksheetName.Cells(Row1, 55) Then
            Region = Region + "@EMEA"
        End If

        If NBG_DataWorksheetName.Cells(Row1, 56) Then
            Region = Region + "@AMERICAS"
        End If

        If NBG_DataWorksheetName.Cells(Row1, 57) Then
            Region = Region + "@GCSA"
        End If

        If NBG_DataWorksheetName.Cells(Row1, 58) Then
            Region = Region + "@JAPAN&KOREA"
        End If

        Issue_SumofShares.Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, 10).Value = Region '< Going to have issues "J" Is not a number - should be 10

        Issue_SumofSharesCnt = Issue_SumofSharesCnt + 1



        ElseIf (NBG_ComparisonRegion.Cells(Row, SOP).Value = "There are no items to show in this view.") Then

     End If

     Next Row1

     Next Row

        Call RemoveDuplicatesCells_EntireRow ' I would remove from the loop - makes your code slow not unless needed

    'VerifySumofShares = Issue_SumofSharesCnt

    MsgBox Issue_SumofSharesCnt

    Debug.Print Issue_SumofSharesCnt

 CleanUp:

       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

       Set NBG_ComparisonRegion = Nothing
       Set NBG_Region = Nothing
       Set Issue_SumofShares = Nothing
       Set NBG_DataWorksheetName = Nothing

     End Sub
```

My suggestion would be something like this.

Comment: .Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "A") Your going to get an error on all of these. "A" has to be a integer.

Comment: thank you a lot , this is really helpful .
i Just wanted to ask how can i modify the (Sub RemoveDuplicatesCells_EntireRow()
) so it just checks if the numbers in the first column are repeated , and if they are , keep only one row (which contains the number in the first column)and delete the other rows which have the repeated number in the first column .

Comment: and if you please can help me and tell me how to call that sub :)

Comment: use "rng.EntireRow.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes " instead of "Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes". To Call the Sub use "Call RemoveDuplicatesCells_EntireRow". Because it is a function it may not work. You may need to make your function into a Sub.

Comment: Is there a reason your using a "Function" rather than a "Sub"?

Comment: I can only assume you are using textboxes so it is tough for me to run the code without trying to recreate your workbook entirely.